# Chrome's V8 marks function for optimization over and over again till it gives up

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, optimization, v8, profiler

I have a `detectSingleScale` JavaScript function which V8 is trying to optimize and as far as I can tell it can't optimize it.

When running Chrome with `--trace_deopt --trace_opt --trace_opt_verbose --code_comments` I see **hundreds of log lines** like below:

```
6087 [found optimized code for 0x1a9b67169161 <JS Function detectSingleScale (SharedFunctionInfo 0x145b5fa71bb1)> at OSR AST id 218]
6088 [didn't find optimized code in optimized code map for 0x145b5fa71bb1 <SharedFunctionInfo detectSingleScale>]
6089 [marking 0x1a9b6721ab91 <JS Function detectSingleScale (SharedFunctionInfo 0x145b5fa71bb1)> for recompilation, reason: hot and stable, ICs with typeinfo: 140/144 (97%), generic ICs: 0/144 (0%)]
6090 [found optimized code for 0x1a9b6721ab91 <JS Function detectSingleScale (SharedFunctionInfo 0x145b5fa71bb1)> at OSR AST id 218]
6091 [didn't find optimized code in optimized code map for 0x145b5fa71bb1 <SharedFunctionInfo detectSingleScale>]
6092 [marking 0x1a9b672c80f1 <JS Function detectSingleScale (SharedFunctionInfo 0x145b5fa71bb1)> for recompilation, reason: hot and stable, ICs with typeinfo: 140/144 (97%), generic ICs: 0/144 (0%)]
6093 [found optimized code for 0x1a9b672c80f1 <JS Function detectSingleScale (SharedFunctionInfo 0x145b5fa71bb1)> at OSR AST id 218]
6094 [didn't find optimized code in optimized code map for 0x145b5fa71bb1 <SharedFunctionInfo detectSingleScale>]
6095 [marking 0x1a9b67379db1 <JS Function detectSingleScale (SharedFunctionInfo 0x145b5fa71bb1)> for recompilation, reason: hot and stable, ICs with typeinfo: 140/144 (97%), generic ICs: 0/144 (0%)]
```

- V8 marks the `detectSingleScale` function for optimization.
- Then it says that it found the optimized version.
- But then it says that it **didn't** find it. And the whole process restarts over and over again.

The addresses for the optimized code are all different. I'm wondering what could trigger such a V8 behavior. Under which circumstance can a function put V8 in such a state?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the trace it seems that `detectSingleScale` is a new closure every time. It is optimized every time via OSR (*on stack replacement*), so it does not have an non OSR version cached.

The first time you create and run the closure it gets optimized via OSR and resulting code it put into a cache.

Next time you create a closure again you first get `didn't find optimized code` message - `Factory::NewFunctionFromSharedFunctionInfo`[1] tries to look up a **non**-OSR version (OSR id is set to `BailoutId::None()`) and doesn't find any because the only optimized version is OSR one.

Then V8 sees the hot loop and decides to OSR the function - this time it finds already optimized code *with a matching OSR id* in the cache and uses it.

Here is a repro to illustrate this

```
function foo() {
  print('! creating bar')
  var bar = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
      // OSR happens in this loop.
    }

    // Add a literal here to ensure we hit Runtime_NewClosure
    // instead of FastNewClosureStub - stub doesn't log anything.
    var a = [];
  }

  print('! running bar')
  bar();
  print('-- done')
}

foo();
foo();
foo();
```

When I run this file with `d8` I get:

```
$ out/ia32.release/d8 --trace-opt test.js
! creating bar
! running bar
[marking 0x4301b705 <JS Function bar (SharedFunctionInfo 0x4c208765)> for recompilation, reason: small function, ICs with typeinfo: 2/2 (100%), generic ICs: 0/2 (0%)]
[compiling method 0x4301b705 <JS Function bar (SharedFunctionInfo 0x4c208765)> using Crankshaft]
[optimizing 0x4301b705 <JS Function bar (SharedFunctionInfo 0x4c208765)> - took 0.082, 0.119, 0.047 ms]
-- done
! creating bar
[didn't find optimized code in optimized code map for 0x4c208765 <SharedFunctionInfo bar>]
! running bar
[marking 0x4301bdb5 <JS Function bar (SharedFunctionInfo 0x4c208765)> for recompilation, reason: small function, ICs with typeinfo: 2/2 (100%), generic ICs: 0/2 (0%)]
[found optimized code for 0x4301bdb5 <JS Function bar (SharedFunctionInfo 0x4c208765)> at OSR AST id 10]
-- done
! creating bar
[didn't find optimized code in optimized code map for 0x4c208765 <SharedFunctionInfo bar>]
! running bar
[marking 0x4301be35 <JS Function bar (SharedFunctionInfo 0x4c208765)> for recompilation, reason: hot and stable, ICs with typeinfo: 2/2 (100%), generic ICs: 0/2 (0%)]
[found optimized code for 0x4301be35 <JS Function bar (SharedFunctionInfo 0x4c208765)> at OSR AST id 10]
-- done
```

[1] https://github.com/v8/v8-git-mirror/blob/master/src/factory.cc#L1396-L1397

Answer (score 0):

The V8 team currently works on optimizing this case: [Chrome issue tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=5512).

You can run with `--mark_shared_functions_for_tier_up` to use the work in progress. Then `detectSingleScale` should be optimized.

The message `didn't find optimized code in optimized code map for` was not very useful and was deleted from the code base recently.